# Употребление кавычек

Tags: пунктуация

В тексте автор приводит обозначения нескольких заимствованных иностранных слов. Как здесь правильно расставить кавычки?

Предложения привожу с авторской пунктуацией.

«Авто» — «само», «мобиль» — «движущийся». «Пассе» — проходить, «порт» —
дверь. Паспорт — дословно «дверепроход», по-русски — пропуск. Ведь «вуаль» — это парус.

Мне кажется, правильно еще поменять местоположение тире в последнем предложении: Паспорт дословно — «дверепроход», по-русски — пропуск.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Или все слова в кавычка, или все без них. Смысла как-то выделять какие-то из общей массы не вижу.

Перенести тире - согласен.

Comment: Спасибо большое.